# How to create and populate a room database based on the exported schema JSON file?

Tags: android, android-room

I need to provide a prepopulated room database to my app. My understanding of the necessary steps is as follows:

1. export schema
2. using the schema create a database
3. fill the database with data
4. export the filled database to a `.db` file
5. pass the `.db` file to [`RoomDatabase.Builder.createFromAsset`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#createfromasset)

I successfully passed the first step by setting `room.schemaLocation` and now have the exported schema as JSON file.

This is where I am now in trouble:

- How do I create a database (step 2) from a JSON file?
- After I filled the anyhow created database, how do I create a `.db` file (step 4) from it?

Hint: I prefer to fill the database (step 3) from Kotlin code.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to have Room create an empty database for me normally. I then copy the database off the device for use as my starting point. That basically covers steps 1 and 2. Step 4 does not exist, insofar as the SQLite database *is* the `.db` file.

Comment: How do you handle that? Do you comment / change some code so you get an empty database to start with? Is there any practical way to do that more automatically/more secure (secure = can't forget to revert changes)

Comment: "Do you comment / change some code so you get an empty database to start with?" -- generally, yes, but I haven't had frequently-changing schemas, so this has not been a big issue. "Is there any practical way to do that more automatically/more secure" -- I am uncertain what would qualify. For example, you could control whether or not you use `createFromAsset()` via a `BuildConfig` flag, then control that by a custom build variant. To create the empty database, you would run the app using that variant, rather than your normal one that you use for day-to-day development.